# PHP Estructurado realizar test

Tags: php, html, web

Que tal queria saber si hay forma de realizar test e integracion continua sobre funciones utilizando php estructurado, las cuales serian para conexion a base de datos y hacer ABM de imagenes y textos.

Estuve buscando y no encontre nada de utilidad, solo que si es posible hacerlos pero usando php con objetos.

Gracias

Comment: Se pueden escribir cualquier cantidad de tests usando phpUnit, las pruebas se ejecutan fácilmente.

Comment: Hola si estuve un rato buscando y vi que se puede , ahora ando viendo como instalar el phpunit y como tendria que hacer el test de envio mail y base de datos

Comment: Normalmente se integra a un IDE, yo uso NetBeans y después de la integración las pruebas se lanzan con f6 pero puedes usarlo desde línea de comandos también.

Comment: Logre configurar el eclipse cmo IDE con el phpUnit , ahora ando viendo de encontrar ejemplos de que testear del envio de mail con la libreria de phpmailer